# jQuery on click function or random quote machine and JSON API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

For the first time using JSON API. Please tell me where and what I'm doing wrong. This is a challenge from freeCodeCamp. We need to do build a random quote machine.

Once I click on New Quote button is should give us a random quote. In jQuery I'm looping through json and on click function has to change me current h2 class = text with the new random quote from JSON.

Project is here http://codepen.io/ekilja01/full/Lbdbpd/.

Please help.

Here is my **HTML**:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class = "well">


<div class="row">

<h2 class="text text-center"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"> </i> Hey, what when and why there is no and yes?</h2>


 <p class="author">-Alina Khachatrian</p>



<div class="buttons">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <a id="tweet-quote" title="Tweet current quote" target="_blank" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
  </a> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
  <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default btn-transparent" id ="getNewQuote" title="Get a new quote">New Quote</button>
</div>
</div>
<footer class="text-center">
<hr>
<p>Written and coded by <a href="https://github.com/edkiljak">Edgar Kiljak</a>.</p>
</footer>  
</div>
</div>
```

and **JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".btn").on("click", function(){
  $.getJSON("http://quotes.rest/qod.json", function (json) {

var html = "";

json.forEach(function(val){
  var keys = Object.keys(val);
    html += "<div class = 'newQuote>'";

    "<h2 = '" + val.quote + "'>";

     html += "</h2>";


     html += "</div>";
})

$(".text").html(html);
});
});
```

});

and **JSON**:

```
{
  "success": {
    "total": 1
 },
 "contents": {
 "quotes": [
    {
        "quote": "Great things are done by a series of small things brought together.",
        "length": "67",
        "author": "Vincent Van Gogh",
        "tags": [
            "inspire",
            "small-things",
            "tso-art"
        ],
        "category": "inspire",
        "date": "2016-12-10",
        "title": "Inspiring Quote of the day",
        "background": "https://theysaidso.com/img/bgs/man_on_the_mountain.jpg",
        "id": "DLThmumKP4CCe1833rRvNQeF"
    }
]
}
}
```

Comment: `Please tell me where and what I'm doing wrong.` - you need to state your objective and where you think the current code isn't delivering your objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is here: `json.forEach(function(val)`...

since the JSON is not an array, it should be: `json.contents.quotes.forEach(function(val)`
`json.contents.quotes` is an array ([brackets] instead of {}) and forEach is only for arrays

Comment: you should also look into Himanshu's answer, he also caught a bug in you're code

Comment: I have changed my h2 thank you and also after changing json.contents.quotes.forEach(function(val)  something happening. After I click new quote button my existing text in h2 disappears but new one is not adding. Please have a look http://codepen.io/ekilja01/full/Lbdbpd/

Comment: this line:  "<h2>'" + val.quote + "'</h2>"; does not get attached to `html` var.
also, you are placing the new `h2` inside a `div` inside the old `h2`, not an error but just messy

Comment: I have changed json api to this: http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/quotes.json and trying to loop through it with forEach json.quote.forEach(function(val) but it doesn't work. http://codepen.io/ekilja01/pen/Lbdbpd

Comment: in this one you don't need to add the '.quote' since it's already an array (again, notice the square brackets []) so you need ` json.forEach`

Comment: Right now I've got it. The other thing if you look at codepen now all quotes appears on the same page after click button. How can split it up by one quote per click? Sorry for asking this silly questions.

Comment: in that case - you shouldn't use forEach (since it runs the code for each object) and maybe something with a random index between 0 and the length of the array: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYMrBd

Comment: Thank you very much Jameson. I have learned a lot today. Can I please ask you one last question. How can we change existing  <p class="author">-Alina Khachatrian</p> with an author from an array.

Comment: just add `$('.author').text(val.author);` like here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYMrBd happy to help, have e great week!

Answer (score 0):

**Please post the error you are getting.**

Also in your .js file, you are doing :

```
"<h2 = '" + val.quote + "'>";
```

which should be

```
  "<h2>'" + val.quote + "'</h2>";
```

Another advice would be to put the code where you are handling the response in .done(). This method as far as I know, is available with the $.get() method.

From the jQuery [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/%20docs),

```
$.get( "test.cgi", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } )
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```